# Issue with Hiding Taskbar in Latest Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: taskbar

I've installed the latest Raspberry Pi OS and can't find the option to hide the taskbar anymore. Previously, I right-clicked on the taskbar and chose something like "Panel Layout" (translated from Norwegian) to auto-hide it. Now, this option seems missing, and "Taskbar Preferences..." doesn't offer a hiding feature.

Is there a new way to hide the taskbar in the latest OS version, or a command-line method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rolling back to the "Legacy 64 bit version" to avoid this undocumented issue.